# Manipulating index of array dynamically in javascript, just like we do this for object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

This question is basically asked for `redux state manipulation ease if one has to return array instead of object in redux array`
For manipulating dynamic property of object, we do like this

```
const myObj = {
   name : 'any name',
   email : 'any email',
   dob : 'any dob'
}
```

If I want to return new object after manipulating it 
and I want to manipulate properties dynamically from a single
function I can do it with ease

```
return {
  ...myObj,
  [action.dynamicProp] : action.anyValue
}
```

But if I want to do the same with array, I can' t able to do that with spread syntax

```
const myArr = ['value1','value2','value3'];
return [...myArr,?????????]
```

So is it possible to do this using spread syntax?
(One can do this without spread operator but the point is to do it with spread syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with spread, but you also have to `.slice` the portions of the array before and after the item you want to replace and spread them into the new array. For example, to replace the item at index 1:

```js
const myArr = ['value1','value2','value3'];
const index = 1;
const output = [
   ...myArr.slice(0, index),
   'newItem',
   ...myArr.slice(index + 1),
];
 console.log(output);
```

You can also make a shallow copy of the array and assign to an index, but that's less functional:

```js
const myArr = ['value1','value2','value3'];
const index = 1;
const output = [...myArr];
output[index] = 'newItem';
 console.log(output);
```

Comment: I was trying to manipulate array which had deep object. You saved my time